# Replacing tilde with $HOME in simple shell

Tags: shell, unix, environment-variables, tilde

I am writing a simple Unix shell in C. Here's what I have so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    char x[256], y[256], z[256];
    while (1) {
        getcwd(y, sizeof(y));
        printf("%s$ ", y);
        fgets(x, sizeof(x), stdin);
        if (x[0] == 'c' && x[1] == 'd' && x[2] == ' ') {
            sscanf(x, "cd %s", &z);
            chdir(z);
        }
        else if (strcmp(x, "exit\n") == 0) break;
        else system(x);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What I would like to do is make the tilde character (~) and $HOME interchangeable. I figured I could do this with a simple find-and-replace function. Does anyone know of such a thing?

Comment: To resemble a real shell, you don't want them to be interchangeable -- then you won't be able to input tilde at all. You can start with replacing *unquoted* tilde in the beginning of the word with the value of `$HOME`.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is `strstr()`, which locates a substring in a string, and strchr() which locates a single character. When you've found the start index, then you would copy the parts of the string before and after the `~` into a new string.

[An implementation of str_replace is included in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689235/is-there-any-way-to-improve-this-function-which-replaces-occurrences-of-substring).